# Website navigation bars icon not working properly,

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to make a navigation bar that has links as texts for devices with bigger screens such as monitors, laptops etc.

But a navigationbars icon that upon being clicked, darkens the screen with a new very dark background and lists out the items inside the `<ul>` tag of the navigation bar, which are among the most basic yet crucial links in my website in my navigation bar.

I have managed to write the code for that, and so far I have managed to get the navigation bars icon to appear on the smaller devices as I want them to and the navigation lists out the links of the various pages on my site perfectly fine too.

But when the navigation bars icon is clicked upon on smaller devices, nothing happens. I want the content beneath the navigation bar to darken and then display the links of my site in a vertical line as there is not enough screen space to display all those links on smaller devices.

Please help me out with this functionality!

```css
body {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  background-color: #333;
}

nav {
  background: #333;
  height: 60px;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
  align-items: center;
  padding: 0 20px;
  width: 100%;
}

.logo {
  color: #fff;
  font-size: 24px;
}

.nav-links {
  list-style: none;
  display: flex;
  margin-right: 20px;
}

.nav-links li {
  margin-left: 20px;
}

.nav-links a {
  color: #fff;
  text-decoration: none;
}

.search-form {
  display: flex;
  margin-left: 20px;
}

.search-form input[type="text"] {
  padding: 5px;
  border: none;
  border-radius: 3px 0 0 3px;
}

.search-form button {
  padding: 5px 10px;
  background: #555;
  border: none;
  color: #fff;
  border-radius: 0 3px 3px 0;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.menu-toggle {
  display: none;
  align-items: center;
  cursor: pointer;
  padding: 0 20px;
}

.overlay {
  display: none;
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  background: rgba(0,0,0,0.9);
  z-index: 1;
}

.menu-open .nav-links {
  display: block;
  position: fixed;
  top: 60px;
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
  background: #333;
  z-index: 2;
  padding: 10px;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

.menu-open .nav-links li {
  margin-left: 0;
  padding: 5px 0;
}

.menu-open .nav-links li:first-child {
  padding-top: 0;
}

.menu-open .nav-links li:last-child {
  padding-bottom: 0;
}

.menu-open .nav-links li a {
  display: block;
  padding: 5px 0;
  border-bottom: 1px solid #555;
}

.menu-open .logo,
.menu-open .nav-links li a {
  color: #fff;
}

@media only screen and (max-width: 768px) {
  .menu-toggle {
      display: flex;
  }

  .nav-links {
      display: none;
  }

  .search-form {
      margin-left: auto;
  }

  .search-form input[type="text"] {
      padding: 8px;
      border-radius: 3px;
  }

  .search-form button {
      padding: 8px 15px;
      border-radius: 3px;
  }

  nav {
      padding: 10px;
  }

  .nav-links li {
      margin-left: 0;
      padding: 5px 0;
  }

  .nav-links li:first-child {
      padding-top: 0;
  }

  .nav-links li:last-child {
      padding-bottom: 0;
  }

  .nav-links li a {
      display: block;
      padding: 5px 0;
      border-bottom: 1px solid #555;
  }


  .logo {
      display: none;
  }
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" contents="'ie=edge">
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="{% static 'base.css' %}">
    <script src="https://kit.fontawesome.com/e67857e448.js" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    {% block stylesheet %} {% endblock %}
    <link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.3.0/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css"
        rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-9ndCyUaIbzAi2FUVXJi0CjmCapSmO7SnpJef0486qhLnuZ2cdeRhO02iuK6FUUVM"
        crossorigin="anonymous">
    {% if title %}
    <title>{{ title }}</title>
    {% else %}
    <title>Random title</title>
    {% endif %}
</head>

<body>
    <nav>
        <div class="menu-toggle">
            <input type="checkbox" id="check" style="display: none;">
            <label for="check" class="checkbtn">
                <i class="fa-solid fa-bars"></i>
            </label>
        </div>
        <div class="logo">Website Name</div>
        <ul class="nav-links">
            <li><a href="{% url 'common-anime-chat-home' %}">Home</a></li>
            <li><a href="{% url 'register' %}">Register</a></li>
            {% if request.user.is_authenticated %}
            <li><a href="{% url 'logout' %}">Logout</a></li>
            <li><a href="{% url 'profile' %}">Profile</a></li>
            <li><a href="{% url 'user_chat' %}">My Chats</a></li>
            {% else %}
            <li><a href="{% url 'login' %}">Login</a></li>
            {% endif %}
            <li><a href="">About Us</a></li>
        </ul>
        <form class="search-form" action="{% url 'search_users' %}" method="GET">
            <input type="text" placeholder="Search...">
            <button type="submit">Search</button>
        </form>
    </nav>
    <div class="overlay"></div>
    {% if messages %}
    <div class="alert alert-success" role="alert" style="margin-bottom: 0px;">
        {% for message in messages %}
        {{ message }}
        <br>
        {% endfor %}
    </div>
    {% endif %}
    {% block content %}{% endblock %}
    {{ request.user.id|json_script:"user_id" }}
    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.3.0/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js"
        integrity="sha384-geWF76RCwLtnZ8qwWowPQNguL3RmwHVBC9FhGdlKrxdiJJigb/j/68SIy3Te4Bkz"
        crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/@popperjs/core@2.11.8/dist/umd/popper.min.js"
        integrity="sha384-I7E8VVD/ismYTF4hNIPjVp/Zjvgyol6VFvRkX/vR+Vc4jQkC+hVqc2pM8ODewa9r"
        crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.3.0/dist/js/bootstrap.min.js"
        integrity="sha384-fbbOQedDUMZZ5KreZpsbe1LCZPVmfTnH7ois6mU1QK+m14rQ1l2bGBq41eYeM/fS"
        crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

Generated HTML code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" contents="'ie=edge">
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/static/base.css">
    <script src="https://kit.fontawesome.com/e67857e448.js" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/static/index.css">

    <link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.3.0/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css"
        rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-9ndCyUaIbzAi2FUVXJi0CjmCapSmO7SnpJef0486qhLnuZ2cdeRhO02iuK6FUUVM"
        crossorigin="anonymous">
    
    <title>Random title</title>
    
</head>

<body>
    <nav>
        <div class="menu-toggle">
            <input type="checkbox" id="check" style="display: none;">
            <label for="check" class="checkbtn">
                <i class="fa-solid fa-bars"></i>
            </label>
        </div>
        <div class="logo">Website Name</div>
        <ul class="nav-links">
            <li><a href="/">Home</a></li>
            <li><a href="/register/">Register</a></li>
            
            <li><a href="/logout/">Logout</a></li>
            <li><a href="/profile/">Profile</a></li>
            <li><a href="/chats/">My Chats</a></li>
            
            <li><a href="">About Us</a></li>
        </ul>
        <form class="search-form" action="/search-users" method="GET">
            <input type="text" placeholder="Search...">
            <button type="submit">Search</button>
        </form>
    </nav>
    <div class="overlay"></div>
    
    
<section class="content-section" style="height: 23%;">
    <div class="content-container">
      <div class="image-container">
        <img src="/static/anime-girl.png" alt="Image">
      </div>
      <div class="text-container" style="width: 100%;">
        <h2 style="width: 100%;">Start Chat</h2>
        <p style="width: 100%;">Click on the Start Chat button</p>
        <a href="/start-chat/">
          <button class="start-chat-btn">Start Chat</button>
        </a>
      </div>
    </div>
</section>

    <script id="user_id" type="application/json">3</script>
    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.3.0/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js"
        integrity="sha384-geWF76RCwLtnZ8qwWowPQNguL3RmwHVBC9FhGdlKrxdiJJigb/j/68SIy3Te4Bkz"
        crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/@popperjs/core@2.11.8/dist/umd/popper.min.js"
        integrity="sha384-I7E8VVD/ismYTF4hNIPjVp/Zjvgyol6VFvRkX/vR+Vc4jQkC+hVqc2pM8ODewa9r"
        crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.3.0/dist/js/bootstrap.min.js"
        integrity="sha384-fbbOQedDUMZZ5KreZpsbe1LCZPVmfTnH7ois6mU1QK+m14rQ1l2bGBq41eYeM/fS"
        crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
        <script>
            function updateActiveStatus(isActive) {
            console.log("Updating active status");
            const userId = JSON.parse(document.getElementById('user_id').textContent);
            console.log("UserID: " + userId);

            // Create a data object with the user_id and is_active status
            const data = {
                user_id: userId,
                is_active: isActive,
            };
            console.log("JSON stringified data: "+JSON.stringify(data));

            // Fetch API to send the update request
            fetch('/update_active_status/', {
                method: 'POST',
                headers: {
                    'Content-Type': 'application/json',
                    'X-Requested-With': 'Fetch',
                    'X-CSRFToken': 'dyLIGhCeJRoAsBlVMkgB9PCcswEbBY9dzADAsFuHBzTW91otwajDbAz6yKymHDPY',
                },
                body: JSON.stringify(data),
            })
            .then(response => {
                if (!response.ok) {
                    throw new Error('Network response was not ok');
                }
                return response.json();
            })
            .then(data => {
                console.log('Active status updated');
                console.log('Data status: ' + data.status);
            })
            .catch(error => {
                console.error('Error updating active status:', error);
            });
        }

        document.addEventListener('visibilitychange', function() {
            console.log('Visibility state changed. New state:', document.visibilityState)
            if (document.visibilityState === 'visible') {
                console.log("Visible");
                updateActiveStatus(true);
            } else {
                console.log("Not visible");
                updateActiveStatus(false);
            }
        });

        updateActiveStatus(true);
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Please post a [mre]. As the issue has nothing to do with django nor the template, please post the generated HTML and not the actual template...

Comment: @DarkBee I have added the generated HTML code in the edited post so please check it out!